# Doctrine2 query builder return only related entity after join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I wrote a query with query builder, but I cannot find a way to only return an array of Account entities. Basically I make a query on the account_packages table, but then I need to return account entites, which are from another table. Is it possible with one query?

```
public function getAccountsWhichLocationPackagesExpire(DateTime $dateExpire)
{
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('p')
        ->from('ServicePaymentBundle:AccountPackage', 'p')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('p.dateExpire', ':dateExpire'))
        ->andWhere('p.alias = :alias')
        ->andWhere('p.enabled = :enabled')
        ->setParameter('dateExpire', $dateExpire->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->setParameter('alias', Package::TYPE_LOCATION)
        ->setParameter('enabled', 1)
        ->leftJoin('p.account', 'a');

    try {
        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); # Here I only need an array of account entities, not account packages. It would be nicer if they were distinct.
        # echo count($result);
        return $result;
    }
    catch(NoResultException $e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should invert your query. Select from `Accounts` and join with `AccountPackage`. Something like this:

```
$qb->select('a')
    ->from('ServicePaymentBundle:Account', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('a.accountPackages', 'p')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('p.dateExpire', ':dateExpire'))
    ->andWhere('p.alias = :alias')
    ->andWhere('p.enabled = :enabled')
    ->setParameter('dateExpire', $dateExpire->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->setParameter('alias', Package::TYPE_LOCATION)
    ->setParameter('enabled', 1);
```

This will work only if your relation is bi-directional. Like:

in `Account` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SomePath\AccountPackage", inversedBy="account")
 */
private $accountPackages;
```

and in `AccountPackage` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SomePath\Account", inversedBy="accountPackages")
 */
private $account;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my relation is not bi-directional. One account can have more packages (one-to-many), so there is no accountPackage attribute in account table.

Comment: So add one. You can add mapping attribute to one-to-many relation.

Comment: I have modyfied my answer to cover `ManyToOne` relation. (chenge accountPackage to $accountPackages)